# Pvalue comparison at group or level

Tags: fishers-exact-test

I am looking at pvalue. 2 groups x 4 levels. I ran a fishers exact test and got a pvalue. Does that pvalue relate to the group comparison as a whole or to a comparison of each individual level?

Can I say group 1 level 2 is significantly different than group 2 level 2 at the pvalue of 0.117 found from the fisher test group comparison?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! It might help to show your contingency table. I couldn't tell whether it's a 2x4 or a 4x4 one.

Comment: It’s a 2x4 table. 1 grouping variable X (A/B) with 2 levels and 1 variable Y with 4 levels (1-4). P=.117. Is that just for the association of variables X and Y or can I say the association of Var X A1 and Var Y A1 is .117?

Comment: You describe a *single* p value.  Could you clarify how that might be interpreted in terms of "comparison[s] of each individual level," of which there are $6$ possibilities?

Comment: That is my question. Is the single pvalue applicable to all comparison levels or only applicable to the two variables overall? Variable A has A1-A2 and B has B1-B4. Does fisher exact tell me the association of variable A and B only or can I say that .117 is applicable to A1/B1 and A2/B1?

Comment: Please visit https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts to merge your accounts: this will enable you to edit your question.